# rails update_attributes returns false when trying to update db values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, update-attributes

hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

I have a controller Update def running "update_attributes". Currently it returns false, with no error message. I'm fairly new to Ruby, but not to coding, and this has had me stumped for a good few days! I am trying to get the User  model and db updated with the values specified below.

```
def update   
    #get currently logged in user
    @user = current_user
    #update user params based on edit form...
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        redirect_to profile_path, :notice  => "Successfully updated profile."
    else
        render :action => 'edit'
    end
end
```

my edit def....

```
def edit
    @user = current_user
end
```

The form sends the following to this update method:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
utf8: ✓
_method: put
authenticity_token: 9T4ihVI0p8j7pZEFxof3Bfahi2a+o3BPmtXJDnfHT4o=
user: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  first_name: Amanda
  last_name: Ross
  is_owner: '1'
  email: example@googlemail.com
commit: Update
action: update
controller: users
id: '20'
```

And params[:user] returns:

```
{"first_name"=>"Amanda", "last_name"=>"Ross", "is_owner"=>"1", "email"=>"example@googlemail.com"}
```

All these fields are in attr_accessible in the Model, and I can create a user without any problem.

here's development.log output (sorry it's a bit messy)....

```
Started PUT "/users/20" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-17 10:39:29 +0100
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9T4ihVI0p8j7pZEFxof3Bfahi2a+o3BPmtXJDnfHT4o=", "user"=>    {"first_name"=>"Amanda", "last_name"=>"Ross", "is_owner"=>"1", "email"=>"example@googlemail.com"},     "commit"=>"Update", "id"=>"20"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 20 LIMIT 1[0m
>>>>>>>>>>>>
{"first_name"=>"Amanda", "last_name"=>"Ross", "is_owner"=>"1", "email"=>"example@googlemail.com"}
     [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  begin transaction
     [1m[36mUser Exists (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") =     LOWER('example@googlemail.com') AND "users"."id" != 20) LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mUser Exists (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'example@googlemail.com'     AND "users"."id" != 20) LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mrollback transaction[0m
 Rendered users/_form.html.erb (7.0ms)
 Rendered users/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (10.0ms)
 Rendered layouts/_includes.html.erb (30.0ms)
```

Could anyone possibly help point out where I'm going wrong, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked `development.log`?

Comment: A description of the error message would be nice - don't know how you're just getting `false`

Comment: added development.log output in the main post.... (just getting a rollback)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Both `#update_attributes` and `#save` will first check if your model instance is `#valid?` before continuing on to write to the database. If your model instance is not `#valid?`, then these methods will return false. To see what's wrong with your model instance, take a look at your model's `#errors`.

```
Rails.logger.info(@user.errors.messages.inspect)
```

Or, embedded in your method,

```
def update   
  @user = current_user
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    redirect_to profile_path, :notice  => "Successfully updated profile."
  else
    # print the errors to the development log
    Rails.logger.info(@user.errors.messages.inspect)
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: That's it! That's exactly what I needed! The error log revealed I was missing a field that needed to be updated along with these. Thanks very much, now I know how to properly debug these errors too! :-)

Comment: I am facing similar problem now, I tried Rails.logger.info(@user.errors.messages.inspect)
 and it returns me "True" . What does it mean?
I have to update a column and I have added the column in attr_accessible. while updating it returns me false and query it is executing is also weird. Have a look here
http://paste.lisp.org/+2S4Y
I cant update the fields. what may be the problem?

Comment: @JyotiRanjan check `@user.errors.messages.inspect` it works at least in my case with Rails 4.2

Answer (score 9):

You can also get better introspection when updating attributes by calling `update_attributes!` instead, which raises exceptions instead of just returning false.